# Devise + Rails 4.1 JSON API: user parameters are not wrapped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Rails 4.1 to build a JSON api with authentication based on Devise. Parameters wrapping is working just fine for my models/controllers using the following config in `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
end
```

But the wrapping is not working for devise controllers. When I post a non rooted json to the devise controllers I get a `422` code.

Any idea how to enable parameter wrapping for devise controllers?

EDIT:

Devise expects the user data to be rooted in the `user` key as follows:

```
{ user: { email: "..", password: ".." } }
```

Whereas with parameter wrapping, I would expect the following json to work:

```
{ email: "..", password: ".." }
```

Comment: Could you share a snippet from your log with the request, parameters and response?

Comment: You propably gets 422 because you don't pass authenticity_token with your request.

Comment: @MichałMłoźniak no it's not a csrf token problem here. Devise expects the json to have this form `{ user: { email: "..", password: ".." }` whereas I want to pass it without user root:`{ email: "..", password: ".." }`

Comment: @wicz added the json expected by devise and the one I'd like to send to my backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following in `wrap_parameters.rb`

```
DeviseController.class_eval <<-EXT
  wrap_parameters :user, format: [:json]
EXT
```

**UPDATE**

A better generic solution would be like this

```
DeviseController.class_eval <<-EXT
  private
  def _wrapper_key
    resource_name
  end
EXT
```

Comment: thank you Ahmad. Any idea why the config in `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb` is discarded by Devise controllers? It is working just fine for other controllers.

Comment: I don't think it's discarded, I think it just does the wrapping wrong. See, if you don't specify a wrapper key (e.g. "user"), Rails derives one from the controller name, so it will be something like "session" when logging-in or "registration" for signing-up and so on, clearly not the keys Devise expects.

Comment: Would `wrap_parameters resource_name, format: [:json]` be probably more generic, I guess?

Comment: I mean replacing the specific `:user` scope by the generic `resource_name` in your code snippet. This would help coping with an admin scope for instance...

Comment: If `resource_name` method is defined in the class context then yes :).

Comment: Actually no, I don't think that would work, please check the updated answer.

Comment: It works like a charm at startup then the changes are 'lost' when the classes are reloaded by rails :( more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585129/controller-monkey-patch-in-initializer-gets-lost-when-rails-loads-classes