# Auto reloading in RubyMine: Changing something destroys app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I am doing my very first steps in Ruby on Rails using the RubyMine IDE.

When I change something (even just inserting a comment) and reload the page, the app crashes.

The error is "NoMethodError" in some controller (this is app specific of course, I am working on Redmine - with EasyRedmine plugins).

- Should I be able to live-edit code without stopping and starting the rails server?
- Is this just a bug in the application?
- Any other hints?

[image]

**Edit** in_mobile_view comes from a patch file (`user_patch.rb`)

There is a line in `plugins/easyproject/easy_plugins/easy_extensions/lib/easy_patch/redmine/models/user_patch.rb`

```
    attr_accessor :in_mobile_view, :in_iframe

    ....

    def in_mobile_view?
      return self.in_mobile_view
    end
```

**Edit2**: After some random Googling I found, that monkey patches might harm the ability of rails to dynamically reload the code: stackoverflow.com/q/26585129/288568

SO I had a closer look at `user_patch.rb`. It starts with:

```
module EasyPatch
  module UserPatch

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
      base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

      base.class_eval do
      ...
```

So this actually seems to be the suggested way of doing the patching and allow for dynamic reloading?

**Edit3**: Here is the trace of applying the patch. And that breakpoint seems to not be hit again, if I typ a comment to the class and hit save.

[image: Trace]

Comment: Rubymine has an auto save feature that saves the code automatically.  Yes you can live edit without restarting.

Comment: Okay, cool - if it would work :)

Comment: What do you mean if it would work?

Comment: This behavior isn't typical. Could the answer be in how in_mobile_view is defined?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth is it maybe because it comes from a patch file - whatever that is?

Comment: What directory is the patch in?

Comment: Edited - what is that patch stuff? Is it standard ruby / rails ? Or redmine specific?

Comment: Probably this is the Problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/26585129/288568

Comment: Next I'd want to see how the patch module is included. I'm wondering if it's done in a way that doesn't happen when Rails autoloads `User`.